# How do I make bash script wait until kubernetes pods restart?

Tags: linux, bash, kubernetes, grep

I am writing a script, where I want to restart kubernetes pods with the scale-down scale-up method

```
kubectl scale --replicas=0 myPod -n myNamespace
kubectl scale --replicas=3 myPod -n myNamespace
```

I would like the script to wait until the pods are `Running` - so I thought something like

```
while kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Running -n myNameSpace | grep -c myPod = 3;
    do
        sleep 1
        echo "."
    done
```

could work - but no dice. The `= 3` part doesn't work.
I can't just use

```
while kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase!=Running -n myNameSpace | grep -c myPod > /dev/null
```

since the pods start in sequence, and I could get unlucky by querying just as one pod deployed, and others didn't even start.

How can I ensure that the script continues only after all 3 of the pods are `Running`?

Comment: Are you aware of the [`kubectl wait`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait) command, which in 1.23 gain the ability to watch arbitrary fields, or [`kubectl rollout status`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-status-em-), which despite its name waits until the managed pods are all Ready?

Comment: @mdaniel sounds great, but I can't make it work with dynamic pod names. The pods I use will be named akin to `myPod-83dc4a56f7-wrght` based on the build version. Is there a way to run the command for every `myPod` regardless of the specific name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your condition in [ ] and get the value of command with ` or $. for example in your case:

```
while [ "$(kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Running -n myNameSpace | grep -c myPod)" != 3 ]

  do
    sleep 1
    echo "wait"
  done

echo "All three pods is running and continue your script"
```